# C function swallows the first letter of user input string

Tags: c

This function writes to a txt file 3 user inputs; namely the ID, category and description. The ID should be an integer while the others should be strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void addtask();
char menu();

int main() {
    char selection ;
   do {
    selection = menu() ;
    switch(selection) {
        case '1': addtask(); break;
        case '2': break;
        default: printf("\n\n\nInvalid key entered");
    }
   }while(selection != '2');
   return 0;
}

char menu() {
    char option;
    printf("\nWelcome to the task management system. Please enter a key to continue...\n");
    printf("\n1) Add new task");
    printf("\n2) Save and quit\n");
    scanf("%c[^\n]", &option);
    return option;
}

void addtask() {
    int id;char category[21];char description[101];
    printf("\nCreating new task...\n\n");
    FILE * f = fopen("tasklist.txt", "r+");
    if(f == NULL){
        printf("File does not exist. Creating new file...");
        f = fopen("tasklist.txt", "w");
    }
    else {
            fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);  //move to end of cursor
            printf("\nENTER id:");
            scanf("%d", &id);
            printf("\nEnter category (max 20 characters): ");
            getchar();
            fgets(category, 21, stdin);
            printf("\nEnter description (max 100 characters): ");
            getchar();
            fgets(description, 101, stdin);
            printf("writing: %d \t %s \t %s \t", id, category, description);
            fprintf(f,"%d \t %s \t %s \t", id, category, description);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

When I run the program and input 2 sets of ID, category and description, I get in the txt file

```
1    Cat1
     esc1
    2    Cat2
     esc2
```

where I think I should expect

```
1    Cat1   Desc1
2    Cat2   Desc2
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You should never use `fgets()` when you depend on input from outside of the program (like user input) because then your program can very easily be infected.

Comment: Are the outputs of the `printf` and the `fprintf` which follow each other equal?

Comment: The format string for `scanf(”%c[^\n]”, &option);` is implausible.  It will read a character because of the `%c`, but the user has to be extraordinarily prescient to enter an open square bracket and a caret and possibly white space and a close square bracket.  A scan set uses `%[…]` or `%[^…]`.

Comment: The `fgets()` for the category reads the newline too.  The `getchar()` before the next `fgets()` reads and discards the first letter of the description.  Remove it.

Comment: Don't mix `scanf()` and (`fgets()` or `getchar()`). Use exclusively `fgets()` for user input ... possibly followed by `sscanf()` (notice two 's') for lazy parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the mix of `scanf` and `fgets`, you get some weird behavior.

The main issue is the user's "enter" (`\n`) press when writing input to the terminal. `scanf` leaves it be in the `stdin`'s buffer, while `fgets` includes it in the string it puts the input into.
Lets focus in your `addtask` function, inside the `else` brackets:

- `scanf("%d", &id);` takes only the number the user entered, so stdin cleaned off the number, but it still has a`\n` character inside it. The next `getchar()` call discards it, which leaves u with a clean buffer.
- `fgets(category, 21, stdin);` takes the next input the user writes, **including** the `\n` character. You probably want replace it with a `\0` character to match your format. you can do it with a line like: `category[strcspn(category, "\n")] = '\0';` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/15888753).
- Now, the next `getchr()` call simply "swallows" the first letter of the input the user writes next, which explains your missing letters in the descriptions.
- Finally, `fgets(description, 101, stdin);` takes the rest of the user input, including the newline (`\n`) character(which you should probably let be in this case, since you asked for a new line after each description).

Note: To fully match your requested format, you also need to remove the last tab char (`\t`) from the line: `fprintf(f,"%d \t %s \t %s \t", id, category, description);`. Since the last description string (`%s`) already has a new line in it, and you wouldn't want your next line to start with a tab.